# Getting Location and writing on an editText

Tags: java, android, location

```
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity()).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity()).removeLocationUpdates(this);
                    if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0) {
                        int latestLocationIndex = locationResult.getLocations().size() -1;
                        double latitude = locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLatitude();
                        double longitude = locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLongitude();

                        Location location1 = new Location(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        location1.setLatitude(latitude);
                        location1.setLongitude(longitude);
                        fetchAddress(location1);
                        location.setText(address);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have this code to fetch the location from latitude and longitude but it does not working because of the  "`LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity())`" Part it says on the internet that `getActivity()` has to be `MainActivity.this` but it did not work on my situation and also what to write inside of the `new Location(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`. Also it has to be `"ProviderNA"` as the internet said but i couldn't run it with this way. How can i get over it ? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: If your `this` is already an `Activity` class then you can just call `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)`. `getActivity()` is a method on `Fragment` objects.

Comment: I have Fragments also so this does not work.

Comment: If i write "this" gives me an error like error: no suitable method found for getFusedLocationProviderClient(<anonymous LocationCallback>)
                        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).removeLocationUpdates(this);

Comment: you are trying to get location from current lattitude and location right?

Comment: Yes that's right